# Python-linkedin Return URL?

Tags: python, api, oauth, linkedin-api

I am trying to use https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin

The steps I am taking are as follows:

- Register my application on linkedin to get the secret and api key.
- Put the return URI as localhost:8080/code.
- Change authentication.py with all of the information.
- change http_api.py with the information  Keeping the return URL to localhost:8080

I get the error: 
`invalid redirect_uri`. This value must match a URL registered with the API Key.

Can anyone walk me through the steps of what I may be doing wrong? I also get this error sometimes: 
Your+application+has+not+been+authorized+for+the+scope+"r_contactinfo" in the URL when I run authentication.py

Answer (score 0):

Since the last changes in LinkedIn API you have no longer access to the following member permissions:

r_fullprofile, r_network, r_contactinfo, rw_nus, rw_groups, w_messages

https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition